# Override default show option in datatables

Tags: jquery, django, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to override "show entries" option in datatable using jquery provided in datatables documentation. But it looks like datatable js cdn is overriding this to 10 again. After reloading it shows "25" but then again changes to "10" again.

```html
<script>
  $('#items2').dataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [
      [25, 50, -1],
      [25, 50, "All"]
    ]
  });
</script>
<script>
  $('#items').dataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [
      [25, 50, -1],
      [25, 50, "All"]
    ]
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It sounds like you may be re-initialising the datatable after executing these lines of code. Can you please show a more complete example of your Datatable initialisation. Also note that you don't need to separate these JS blocks in to different `<script>` tags, and you can also join the selectors in to a single jQuery object.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thankyou I included ```"lengthMenu": [
      [25, 50, -1],
      [25, 50, "All"]
    ]```

this function in default function of datatable and it worked. Script function now looks like this:

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under your question as code in comments is unreadable

Comment: ```$(document).ready(function () { $('#items2').DataTable({ "pagingType": "full_numbers", "bDestroy": true "lengthMenu": [ [25,30,40,45, 50, -1], [25,30,40,45,50, "All"] ] }); });``` @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

```
         $('#items2').DataTable({
             "pagingType": "full_numbers",
             "bDestroy": true
             "lengthMenu": [ [25,30,40,45, 50, -1], [25,30,40,45,50, "All"] ]
         });
     });
```

I added "lengthMenu" function into default datatable function and it worked.